# A bash script to insert and update serially numbered folder names

Tags: shell, bash

IMPORTANT: See **update-1** below suggesting a new directory structure.

IMPORTANT: See **update-2** below to understand why I'm looking for a bash_script to write my book(s).

IMPORTANT: See **update-3** about requiring an insertPage() command that is separate from addPage().

Final update: Here's the book I wrote using this script!: [Demo-in-Sixty-Seconds](https://bubbl.in/cover/demo-in-sixty-seconds-by-marvin-danig)

---

I was writing a book manually and it has the following `directory` structure:

```
The-Solar-System/
├── README.md
├── css
│   ├── page-1
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── page-2
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── page-3
│       └── style.css
├── head
│   ├── page-1
│   │   └── head.html
│   ├── page-2
│   │   └── head.html
│   └── page-3
│       └── head.html
├── html
│   ├── page-1
│   │   └── body.html
│   ├── page-2
│   │   └── body.html
│   └── page-3
│       └── body.html
├── images
│   └── page-1
│       └── bubblin-publishers-icon-96x96.png
├── js
│   ├── page-1
│   │   └── script.js
│   ├── page-2
│   │   └── script.js
│   └── page-3
│       └── script.js
```

Until now, things were easy and I was doing most of the directory additions / subtractions manually. Now the number of pages (directories with page-numbers) has grown and it has become increasingly difficult to update all the directory names sequentially to insert a new page in between. And when a page is removed.

So I decided to write some scripts and automate this a bit. This is how I want to initialize pages of my book(project). I'm on Mac.

**Step-1 Initialize project** (IMPORTANT: See update-1 below)

> book () { mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1" && mkdir -p "html" "head" "css" "js" "images" "cover" && touch README.md; ll;}

The above works, but I want to iteratively go inside sub-directories `html`, `head`, `css` and so on and create page-directories that are named like this:

```
page-1
page-2
page-3
...
...
page-N
```

Where `N` is a parameter I pass to the script. Something like this:

> $ book MY-BOOK-NAME N

Once the page-directories are created, I want to initialize each page-directory page-1, page-2, and so on with a file named `body.html` if it is inside `html` superdirectory, `style.css` if it is inside `css` directory.

**Step-2 Add page:**

I want to be able to add a page (a folder named `page-P` where `1 < P <= N`) and renaming the existing directories from {page-P to page-N} to {page-P+1 to page-N+1}.

This situation comes when several pages(directories) already exist in the book ranging from `page-1 ... page-(P-1), page-(P), page-(P+1)... page-N` and we want to insert a page in-between.

Roughly the following steps:

1. Take input:

   > $ `addPage() P`

via bash where `page_number`: 'P' must be `1 < P <= N`.

2. Rename all existing directories between {`page-P` to `page-N`} to {`page-(P+1)` to `page-(N+1)`}
3. Create a new_blank_page directory `page-P` with following assets inside it: `body.html`, `style.css` and a blank sub-directory `images`.
4. Echo success message: `Page has been added at 'P'`

**Step-3: Remove page.**

Right now I am unable to do this even manually because renumbering pages after a delete is (according to me) tedious, inefficient, impractical. It'd be nice if there was a command tool to delete-and-renumber pages automatically.

Here's how `remove_page() P` to remove a page-P from in-between the book `(1 < P <= N)` would work:

1. Take command:

   > $ `removePage() P`

via bash where `page_number`: 'P' must be `1 < P <= N`.

2. Delete the directory `page-P` and move the assets inside it: `body.html`, `style.css`others to say a /trash directory inside the project. To soft delete the manuscript pieces only.
3. Rename all existing directories between {`page-P+1` to `page-N`} to {`page-(P)` to `page-(N-1)`}

---

How to modify my script so that I can command these steps from the terminal? Any good articles/sources for beginners that you recommend where I can learn enough about bash programming to do this?

**Update-1**

As suggested in the comments below, doing an inverted hierarchy for directories makes total sense. Somehow this simple thing wasn't apparent to me (feeling stupid) earlier, when I started writing the book and now I will have to redo 76 pages of [my book](https://github.com/bubblin/The-Solar-System) all over again. Phew.

Anyway, the new directory structure will be something like this:

```
The-Solar-System/
├── README.md
├── page-1
│   ├── head.html
│   │   
│   ├── style.css
│   │   
│   ├── body.html
│   │   
│   ├── script.js
│   │   
│   └── images
│       └── cat.png
├── page-2
│   ├── head.html
│   │   
│   ├── style.css
│   │   
│   ├── body.html
│   │   
│   ├── script.js
│   │   
│   └── images
│       └── dog.png
```

... and so on. So the new bash_script has to work something like this:

```
new_book () {
  mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1" 
  touch README.md;
  mkdir cover
  && 
# for loop 1 to N
# mkdir page_directories
# mk
&&  ll;}
```

I'm still thinking how to pass `N` for the number of pages and iteratively create N-pages (defaults to 4 pages minimum) inside the project.

And then look at script for step-2 and step-3, as above.

**Update-2**

There is generally good advice in the answers below about how to write a book and how not to. Unfortunately, most of those answers suffer an assumption that an author always *wants* to create an artifact -- a PDF or an ePub or some sort of file with just simple text and images. This is not true in my case. I'm already using `markdown` or `latex` and other tools as suggested in some of the answers below.

Also, I do not want a book to look like a static website or a single html file i.e webpage.

I already *have a way of writing* my book, and wish to use bash commands to automate some of the steps that I often repeat. Let me explain what is happening here and why I need it:

The book on [The Solar System](https://bubbl.in/book/the-solar-system-by-marvin-danig) that I'm referring to is already written and published online.  It was written using the in-browser code-editor that is available on [Bubblin](http://bubbl.in) (Screenshot below).

[image: Code playground @bubblin]

As a separate exercise I made its source code available on Github, manually.

If you inspect the source of the book on Firebug/Chrome Developer, you'll see that each page is an *iframe* that renders the HTML, CSS and JS just like Codepen/JSFiddle does on runtime, on clientside. So a page here is more like "a single page app" (a webpage) and the book is a collection of such `webpages`. And naturally, the *exercise of writing* here is closer to app/web development than book writing in its ordinary form.

The reason why I'm looking at `bash_commands` is because I am writing two more books and I want to make the code of these books available on Github. For that, I have `git initialized` projects already, but I repeat some steps (discussed above) for every page to hold the pieces together. I think it'd be nice if those steps are automated using a script. It could be done in `Perl`, `Ruby` or `Python` but those in future.

Note I'm eager to keep things DRY, accessible and meaningful as recommended, but it is important to remain flexible about all kinds of books that are possible.

**Update-3**

In course of doing this I realized that insertPage() method had to be different from addPage(); the former inserts in-between, renames and shifts all following directories one up, while the latter goes right to the end of the book.

The [gists of all the bash scripts](https://gist.github.com/bubblin) is available on Github. Nothing fancy, it just gets the job done!

**Update-4**

I went on to create a full framework/CLI tool that lets you write & publish books efficiently: [Bookiza Node CLI](https://github.com/bookiza/bookiza)

Comment: It might be easier to invert your hierarchy and use `book/page##/{js,html,css}` and then have a "compilation" step that merges them. That way renumbering only requires shuffling the toplevel directories.

Comment: Makes sense! There probably isn't need of subdirectories `js, html, css` inside `page##` this way. Unless there is a situation and use for another bunch of html, css or js following an interaction - like form submission. But I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: Yeah, whether or not you split up the files inside the per-page directories is a different conversation (and is relatively easy to change at a later date). The main thing that makes this easier to work with is not splitting up the files per-page in the first place.

Comment: It is similar to ask *I have a website 100 pages and want to create 100 files like script.js, style.css. Does it make sense?*. Any website has more than 1 page but no one create an individual CSS or JS per page.

Comment: It depends. If you're using css to create characters, comic animations or other page specific details then you'll need different css for different pages. That you want to use just one CSS style across the entire book is simply a configuration issue. For example, in this book there is slightly different CSS on different pages: https://bubbl.in/book/demo-in-sixty-seconds-by-marvin-danig

Comment: By the way -- I'd argue that much "obscure syntax" in bash largely exists for purposes of correctness: POSIX sh makes correctness very hard, and many ksh/bash extensions exist to remedy this. As such, though, doing things in a way that doesn't have corner cases tends to have much that's unfamiliar to folks coming from POSIX shell only. The question, then, is not whether you care about readability over efficiency, but whether you value readability over correctness.

Comment: Could you explain more how do you import/export your GitHub repository inside Bubblin?

Comment: It's not there yet @nowox but I see you're already on spot! :) I think it would be nice to have `git push` to do so.

Comment: @marvindanig What I am more asking is what file structure do you need and how do you pack your data to import it on bubblin? Your example shows that you have several piece of code for each page (head, body, css and js) that are somehow merged together by bubblin itself to display the final page. I doubt that Bubblin is keeping all the information as static pages. I guess information is rather storted in a database. To be more helpful I would like to understand what procedure allowed your book to be on Bubblin (or in the other way, on GitHub).

Comment: Okay. Currently the book on Bubblin is created on the site itself. I'm storing the fragments in a database (postgres) and render it on the fly via a `codemirror` instance.  I'm yet undecided about best packing and structure (or none) so that the book is ultimately going to be created locally using sublime/other tools and pushed/updated to bubblin for `live`. I have two books to experiment with and find out which packing one is more suitable/efficient.

Comment: @charlesDuffy I'm not so much of a bash programmer, but I have some `gists` that seem to work decently (on Mac). https://gist.github.com/bubblin  . You're an expert, can you help me review/fix these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code

```
newBook() {
    dir=$1
    N=$2

    mkdir $dir
    i=1
    while [ $i -le $N ]; do
        mkdir ${dir}/page-${i}
        touch ${dir}/page-${i}/head.html
        touch ${dir}/page-${i}/style.css
        touch ${dir}/page-${i}/body.html
        touch ${dir}/page-${i}/script.js
        mkdir ${dir}/page-${i}/images
        i=$(( $i +1 ))
    done
    mkdir ${dir}/trash
}

increasePage(){
    dir=$1
    newPage=$2
    if [ -d ${1}/page-${2} ]; then
        increasePage $1 $(( $2 + 1 ))
        mv ${1}/page-${2} ${1}/page-$(( $2 + 1 ))
    fi
}

CheckPage(){
    #dir=$1
    #newPage=$2
    if [ -d ${1}/page-${2} ]; then
        CheckPage $1 $(( $2 + 1 ))
        return $?
    else
        return $(( $2 - 1 ))
    fi
}

addPage() {
    #dir=$1
    #newPage=$2

    if [ -d ${1}/page-${2} ]; then
        increasePage $1 $2
    fi

    mkdir ${1}/page-${2}
    touch ${1}/page-${2}/head.html
    touch ${1}/page-${2}/style.css
    touch ${1}/page-${2}/body.html
    touch ${1}/page-${2}/script.js
    mkdir ${1}/page-${2}/images 
}

removePage(){
    dir=$1
    pageToRemove=$2

    if [ ! -d ${1}/page-${pageToRemove} ]; then
        echo "Page not Found: $2" >&2
        return
    fi

    mv ${dir}/page-${pageToRemove}/ ${dir}/trash/page-${pageToRemove}.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

    CheckPage $1 $(( $pageToRemove + 1 ))
    count=$?

    while [ $pageToRemove -lt $count ]; do
        mv ${dir}/page-$(( ${pageToRemove} + 1 ))/ ${dir}/page-${pageToRemove}
        pageToRemove=$(($pageToRemove + 1))
    done
}
```

Here is the test execution

```
echo
echo "Creating Book"
newBook project 5

find project -name "*" | sort

echo
echo "placing some images for testing..."
echo touch project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg | sh -v
echo touch project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg | sh -v
echo touch project/page-3/images/Earth.jpg | sh -v
echo touch project/page-4/images/Mars.jpg | sh -v
echo touch project/page-5/images/Jupiter.jpg | sh -v
find project -name "*" | sort

echo
echo "Adding page 3"
addPage project 3

find project -name "*" | sort

echo
echo "Adding page 7"
addPage project 7

find project -name "*" | sort

echo
echo "Removing page 2"
removePage project 2

find project -name "*" | sort
```

And the result

```
Creating Book
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/trash

placing some images for testing...
touch project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
touch project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
touch project/page-3/images/Earth.jpg
touch project/page-4/images/Mars.jpg
touch project/page-5/images/Jupiter.jpg

Adding page 3
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/page-6
project/page-6/body.html
project/page-6/head.html
project/page-6/images
project/page-6/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-6/script.js
project/page-6/style.css
project/trash

Adding page 7
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/page-6
project/page-6/body.html
project/page-6/head.html
project/page-6/images
project/page-6/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-6/script.js
project/page-6/style.css
project/page-7
project/page-7/body.html
project/page-7/head.html
project/page-7/images
project/page-7/script.js
project/page-7/style.css
project/trash

Removing page 2
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/page-6
project/page-6/body.html
project/page-6/head.html
project/page-6/images
project/page-6/script.js
project/page-6/style.css
project/trash
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218/body.html
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218/head.html
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218/images
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218/images/Venus.jpg
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218/script.js
project/trash/page-2.20150811190218/style.css
[opsc@snelnxh51 fabricio]$ rm -r project/
[opsc@snelnxh51 fabricio]$ ./teste.sh

Creating Book
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/trash

placing some images for testing...
touch project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
touch project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
touch project/page-3/images/Earth.jpg
touch project/page-4/images/Mars.jpg
touch project/page-5/images/Jupiter.jpg
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/trash

Adding page 3
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/page-6
project/page-6/body.html
project/page-6/head.html
project/page-6/images
project/page-6/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-6/script.js
project/page-6/style.css
project/trash

Adding page 7
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/images/Venus.jpg
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/page-6
project/page-6/body.html
project/page-6/head.html
project/page-6/images
project/page-6/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-6/script.js
project/page-6/style.css
project/page-7
project/page-7/body.html
project/page-7/head.html
project/page-7/images
project/page-7/script.js
project/page-7/style.css
project/trash

Removing page 2
project
project/page-1
project/page-1/body.html
project/page-1/head.html
project/page-1/images
project/page-1/images/Mercury.jpg
project/page-1/script.js
project/page-1/style.css
project/page-2
project/page-2/body.html
project/page-2/head.html
project/page-2/images
project/page-2/script.js
project/page-2/style.css
project/page-3
project/page-3/body.html
project/page-3/head.html
project/page-3/images
project/page-3/images/Earth.jpg
project/page-3/script.js
project/page-3/style.css
project/page-4
project/page-4/body.html
project/page-4/head.html
project/page-4/images
project/page-4/images/Mars.jpg
project/page-4/script.js
project/page-4/style.css
project/page-5
project/page-5/body.html
project/page-5/head.html
project/page-5/images
project/page-5/images/Jupiter.jpg
project/page-5/script.js
project/page-5/style.css
project/page-6
project/page-6/body.html
project/page-6/head.html
project/page-6/images
project/page-6/script.js
project/page-6/style.css
project/trash
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259/body.html
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259/head.html
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259/images
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259/images/Venus.jpg
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259/script.js
project/trash/page-2.20150811190259/style.css
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you explain in your answer how you are solving the question? :)

Comment: The function newBook receives 2 arguments, The book name and number of pages. It creates the project folder and does a loop creating each page, and its content. Finaly it creates a trash folder.

There is 2 recursive functions, IncreasePage and CheckPage. IncreasePage search by the greater page (the first one it does not have directory created) and moves all pages found to the next page.
CheckPage only search by the greater page and return.

Comment: AddPage check if page already exists. if exists calls IncreasePage to clear the page and creates it.
RemovePage moves the page to trash, calls CheckPage to finds out what is the biggest one and decrease all pages that are bigger than page informed.

Comment: Recursion looks nice! Would have been nicer with some validations though. I'll put some of these into the gists on Github, and credit you for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I may be wrong, but I think you are asking an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

#### You are writing a book in HTML

I am surprised you want to write a book using plain HTML. I think other languages such as [latex](/questions/tagged/latex), [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) or even [lout](/questions/tagged/lout) might be more appropriate for your application.

Of course, nothing will retain you to generate HTML pages later by using tools such as [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc).

Usually, when I have to write a book, I rather want to focus on the content, not the style or the rendering. I bet it would be much better to have your book written in a more generic language that will allow you to generate any other format using either an homemade script or an online converter. With this it will be easy to create a e-book, a pdf, a multiple HTML pages or even a single one.

#### Why dividing the content?

Usually a book has a unified style all along. In your example you mention multiple [css](/questions/tagged/css) files. I don't really understand the purpose of it. Perhaps you can give us more details of you book and the reason why you need such complexity.

Moreover, I think that having one file per page is a bit too excessive. With this you are losing the overall view and you make the book hard to edit and improve. If you still want to write your book in HTML, I might suggest you to have your whole book on one file. A JavaScript script can automatically divide it in chapters and fill a side bar with the table of contents.

#### Why having chosen bash?

Bash is indeed a very powerful language, but it is also quite cryptical and not very designed to do what you want.

I may suggest you to take a look at other languages such as [perl](/questions/tagged/perl),  [python](/questions/tagged/python) or even [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby). With these scripting languages you can easily write a main program with sub-commands and arguments. Wouldn't be more convenient to have something like this:

$ book create --name="My Book" --pages=200
   $ book insert-page --after-page 23
   $ book remove-page 55

However with a single HTML file you will not need the use of such complexity.

#### The-Solar-System

I took a look to your book and I think it suffers of [duplicate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code). Most of your CSS files look the same. Imagine you want to change the default font of all your pages. How will you proceed? You can of course use `find` and `sed` to replace in-place but you will also create a fairly long diff on you next `git commit`. This won't be very helpful to keep track of all you changes.

Consider now the page 42:

```
<div class="leaf ">
  <div class="inner justify">
    <p> <span class="first-word"> M</span>ars is the fourth and the <em>last</em> terrestial planet of our Solar System. What follows beyond Mars are the gas and ice giants - Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune - i.e. planets that do not have a solid rocky
      surface. Given that Mercury and Venus are inhospitable, and we couldn't possibly land on gas giants ever, Mars easily becomes a candidate of great interest to see if it can be terraformed. </p>
    <p> Mars is called the red planet because of its reddish-orange tinge off its iron ( Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron%28III%29_oxide">Iron Oxide / Hematite</a> ) rich soil. It has a thin atmosphere of Carbon Dioxide
      (96%), Argon (1.93%) and Nitrogen (1.89%, along with some traces of Oxygen and moisture. The surface of Mars is like that of our Moon: Scarred with thousands of impact craters. It is also exposed to cosmic and solar radiation in absence of enough
      atmospheric resistance or a decent magnetosphere. </p>
    <p> Mars is roughly half the diameter of Earth but only a tenth its mass. Gravity on Mars is thus significantly lower, about 38% of that on Earth. It also receives much lesser sunlight (about 43% less) than we do on our planet. So far no sign of life,
      not even microbial, has been found on Mars. Though, a few plumes of locally ejected methane from below the surface of Mars were detected. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is really specific here? You need *italic*, maybe **bold** and [hyperlinks](http://www.google.com). All of this is natively supported in [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown). Isn't the following more readable than your html content? Try for example this text on [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/try/) with Markdown set as the input language and HTML as the output one.

```
    Mars is the fourth and the *last* terrestial planet of our Solar
 System. What follows beyond Mars are the gas and ice giants - Jupiter, 
Saturn, Uranus and Neptune - *i.e.* planets that do not have a solid rocky
 surface. Given that Mercury and Venus are inhospitable, and we couldn't
 possibly land on gas giants ever, Mars easily becomes a candidate of great
 interest to see if it can be terraformed.

    Mars is called the red planet because of its reddish-orange tinge off its
 iron ( $Fe_2O_3$ ) [Iron Oxide Hematite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron%28III%29_oxide)) rich soil. It has a thin
 atmosphere of Carbon Dioxide (96%), Argon (1.93%) and Nitrogen (1.89%, along
 with some traces of Oxygen and moisture. The surface of Mars is like that of
 our Moon: Scarred with thousands of impact craters. It is also exposed to
 cosmic and solar radiation in absence of enough atmospheric resistance or a
 decent magnetosphere.

    Mars is roughly half the diameter of Earth but only a tenth its mass.
 Gravity on Mars is thus significantly lower, about 38% of that on Earth. 
It also receives much lesser sunlight (about 43% less) than we do on our 
planet. So far no sign of life, not even microbial, has been found on Mars.
 Though, a few plumes of locally ejected methane from below the surface of 
Mars were detected.
```

#### Are you writing a Gamebook?

I friend of mine wrote an online gamebook available [here](http://www.onivers.com/book/aventure1). It is written in french, but the idea is pretty nice because he wrote a whole online editor available for testing [here](http://www.onivers.com/graph/test1). Each page is a node that can be edited and linked to another nodes. Thus, the whole book isn't written in plain HTML. It is using a database to store all the information.

With this, we can still imagine using GitHub to keep track of your changes and help people to contribute to your book.

#### Conclusion

I don't really think your question will help you writing your book. You rather need to think your project differently and review the overall structure of your book.

Some hints would be:

- Using LaTeX or Markdown as the primary editing language
- Considering tools such as Pandoc for converting your work to other formats
- Avoid redundant information and don't repeat yourself (take a look at [SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth))
- Keep your project simple and stupid ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle))

Comment: I just introduced templates on my application to have default style, head, script or html templates applied across all the pages. Apart from finer per-page control if need be.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_book() {
  mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1" && touch README.md || return $?
  for dir in html head css js images cover; do
    p=1
    while [ "$p" -le "$2" ]; do
      mkdir -p "$dir/page-$p"
      case $dir in
        (html)   f="body.html" ;;
        (css)    f="style.css" ;;
        (*)      continue ;;
      esac
      touch "$dir/page-$p/$f"
      p=$((p+1))
    done
  done
  ls -l
}
```

This should create your requested skeleton structure.  I'd recommend just one `css` directory and a `@include` that pulls in the styles from that one directory, but if you have lots of per-page customization, it would make sense to have one per page.

The first line creates the directory (if it isn't already present), goes inside it, and creates your `README.md`. Any failures there will prevent the rest of the function from running.

After that, there is a loop on each of the subdirectories to create them and each page within them (`mkdir -p` will create missing parent directories).  The `case` statement ensures creating body.html or style.css, or otherwise the loop is continued.

I assume the `ll` at the end of your function was a call to `ls -l` and therefore included it here.  Note that you'll finish in the new book's directory.

Comment: Thanks! css can vary very differently across the pages. There are a few where it varies on every page.

Comment: I tried running this script on my mac, but it failed with the following error: `$ -bash: 1=2: command not found`

Comment: FYI, `return $?` is redundant -- `return` uses the last command's exit status by default.

Comment: @marvindanig, that's because `$p=$((p+1))` needs to be `p=$((p+1))`.

Comment: Also, quotes are needed when using `[`; the line `[ $p -le $2 ]` should be either `[ "$p" -lt "$2" ]` (if targeting POSIX sh), or `(( p <= $2 ))` (if targeting bash); the former is probably a little safer if one wants an empty `$2` to cause an explicit error rather than being treated as 0.

Comment: Yup, @CharlesDuffy found my typo and it is now fixed.  Technically, quotes are only necessary when there might be spaces or unexpected characters, which `$p` will never have, though the `$2` does indeed need to be quoted (including in that `bash` variant). That said, for legibility and good coding practices, it is indeed better to put quotes around the `$p` too.  Also fixed.

Comment: I think you meant "page-$p" since $2 is constant... Then again, you could just decrement $2 and use `while [ "$2" ]`

Comment: I disagree that quotes are unnecessary in other cases. Look at what happens if your function is called with an IFS value containing digits -- and, of course, safety assumes no bugs in your caller leading to an unexpected value for `$2`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I was referring to the number in `$p` which is always a number.  The `$2` must be quoted.

Comment: Even if it's always a number, unquoted numbers can be dangerous if the value of IFS is not controlled. Consider: If IFS=0, then 102 becomes 1 2.

Comment: Redefining `$IFS` in that kind of manner and forgetting to redefine it later will result in far worse issues, but you are technically correct.  (Also note that `1 2` in that example is still understood as `102` and still evaluates correctly; consider `foo() { echo $((($1+$2+$3)/2)); }; foo 1 102 3; export IFS=0; foo 1 102 3` ... though the file names would have spaces in place of zeros).

Comment: @technosaurus is correct, though you can't redefine `$2` without `set` in which case you might as well use a new variable.  fixed.

Comment: @AdamKatz, I disagree re: "far worse issues" -- when I'm writing code, I don't depend on string-splitting without setting IFS explicitly. It's not some mysterious unbounded set of failure cases; they're easy to understand, reason about, and avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Treat your book as website and use common pattern all WEB is using:

```
- Individual HTML static pages or backend
- /images/*.png
- /javascripts/*.js
- /styles/*.css
```

Use CSS selectors to distinct individual styles among pages. Please do not make thing more complex than they should be.

Comment: Book is not the same thing as a website. In case you're unable to see past your assumption about books, please refrain from giving answers that do not supply meaningful response to the question at hand.